# CAGradientLayer frame not displaying properly

Tags: swift, cagradientlayer

I have the following code to present a `CAGradientLayer`, which should cover the whole view. However, it shows up in the simulator not properly. I printed the values of `self.view.bounds.width` and `self.view.bounds.height` which printed the correct values. Below is also the simulator screenshot.

```
// Add background layer to calendar view
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
    gradientLayer.colors = [lightDarkColor.cgColor, darkColor.cgColor, lightDarkColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you comment out the startPoint and endPoint lines?

Comment: @Nick No change, I tested that before :(

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes where you try to add gradient layer? means in which method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `frame` not `bounds`

```
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.frame // here frame = bounds
```